# Javascript property mirroring into another instance

Tags: javascript, properties, overriding

Let's say we have, in Javascript, something like:

```
obj1.prop1.prop1_1.prop1_1_1 = 3;
```

When this is called, I want value 3 to be set up at the same tree location, but in obj2, as if I called:

```
obj2.prop1.prop1_1.prop1_1_1 = 3;
```

all this with the constraint that obj2 is not initially populated with prop1.prop1_1.prop1_1_1.

I guess a first step would be to override obj1.prop1 so it returns obj2.prop1. But obj2.prop1 would need to be assigned to the same type of instance as obj1.prop1. How can we do that?

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly, `obj1.prop1.prop1_1` and `obj2.prop1.prop1_1` are not the same object, and you want setting the `prop1_1_1` propertly on the former to *also* set the same property on the latter.

This is *possible* with [property getters and/or setters](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.2.3.6) as of ES5, but I don't think I'd recommend it. :-)

Here's an example where the getter on `obj2.prop1.prop1_1.prop1_1_1` gets the value from `obj1`'s:

```
var obj1 = {
    prop1: {
        prop1_1: {
            prop1_1_1: 42
        }
    }
};
var obj2 = {
    prop1: {
        prop1_1: {
        }
    }
};
Object.defineProperty(obj2.prop1.prop1_1, "prop1_1_1", {
    get: function() {
        return obj1.prop1.prop1_1.prop1_1_1;
    }
});
console.log("obj1.prop1.prop1_1.prop1_1_1 = " + obj1.prop1.prop1_1.prop1_1_1); // 42
console.log("obj2.prop1.prop1_1.prop1_1_1 = " + obj2.prop1.prop1_1.prop1_1_1); // 42
obj1.prop1.prop1_1.prop1_1_1 = 3;
console.log("obj1.prop1.prop1_1.prop1_1_1 = " + obj1.prop1.prop1_1.prop1_1_1); // 3
console.log("obj2.prop1.prop1_1.prop1_1_1 = " + obj2.prop1.prop1_1.prop1_1_1); // 3
```

[Live Copy](http://jsbin.com/imajef/1) (look in the console) | [Source](http://jsbin.com/imajef/1/edit)

Comment: just to clarify, ES5 means ECMAScript 5 which is the Javascript standard for implementations. Most recent browsers support it but most notably IE8 and older versions do not support it. See: http://kangax.github.com/es5-compat-table/ for a list of browsers that support "Setter in property initializer". My answer will work on those browsers though.

Comment: Thanks T.J. this solves part of my problem. I would have needed though to have obj2 not populated at all, so prop1 and prop1_1 would be need to be created in obj2 on the fly, and the ability to parse the property tree of obj2 afterwards. This way I can know from obj2 all the modifications that have been made into obj1. But I guess this is not possible. In fact to clarify my intent, I need to have obj2 behave like on observer to the modifications made to obj1.

Comment: @Alio: If you need `obj2` to reflect *all* changes made to `obj1`, why not just do `obj2 = obj1;`? Then both variables point to the same object tree, and so (of course) any changes you make via one of them are visible via the other, as they both point to the same tree. If that doesn't work, I'm curious: What *is* the use case?

Answer (score 1):

if T.J. Crowder assumption is correct you can do the following:

```
obj1.prop1.prop1_1.prop1_1_1= [3]


obj2.prop1.prop1_1.prop1_1_1= obj1.prop1.prop1_1.prop1_1_1
```

now if you change obj2.prop1.prop1_1.prop1_1_1[0], obj1.prop1.prop1_1.prop1_1_1[0] will also be changed.

This is because when you define it as [3] it actually creates an Array object and stores its reference (aka pointer) in obj1.prop1.prop1_1.prop1_1_1, so both obj1.prop1.prop1_1.prop1_1_1 and obj2.prop1.prop1_1.prop1_1_1 will have the same reference to the same array. There is only one array in memory, but two references to it, changing one will also change the other.

If you use obj1.prop1.prop1_1.prop1_1_1= 3, in this case prop1_1_1 is a primitive and not a reference to an object. So if you say

```
obj1.prop1.prop1_1.prop1_1_1= obj2.prop1.prop1_1.prop1_1_1
```

it will actually copy the value 3 to the other variable, making it two different places in the memory hold the value 3 and changing one will not change the other